# OMP making a thread wait for a condition

Tags: c, openmp, pragma

I have to make an odd thread (ex 1,3,5,...) wait for an even thread (ex 0,2,4,...) to finish before the first one.

I thought I could use `pragma omp barrier` but it doesn't work the way I want.

Is there any way to make threads wait for a condition to accomplish in order to keep them going?

Part of the code:

```
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:totalSum) private(i, tn)
{
    tn = omp_get_thread_num();
    int lim = 0;
    #pragma omp for
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        v[i] = i+1;
        lim = lim + 1;
        partialSum[tn] = partialSum[tn] + v[i];

        if(lim == 20){
            //make odd threads wait for an even thread to finish before they can finish
            totalSum += partialSum[tn]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code already posted.

Comment: Why?  I mean, I don't see how, in your sample code, you could detect whether the threads waited as you describe or not.  Seems like an X-Y problem to me.

Comment: We'd need to see some more of your code. Particularly, how `partialSum` and `v` are used elsewhere. The usual way to do this is [sum an array of values] is: `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:totalSum) for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) totalSum += array[i];`

Comment: At the moment, what you are trying to achieve is far from clear. The context is important because there may be algorithms that achieve the same result while being better suited to parallelization. Having to rely on heavy synchronization while doing relatively easy tasks is a performance killer.

Comment: Sorry for this late response, I will try to reply to all of you in this message.
-@JohnBollinger the only thing I want to know if there is any option to make a thread wait for a condition (just like a semaphore does).
-@CraigEstey After this part I only print those variables via `printf`.
-@Brice It's a parallelization excersice for one of my subjects. Nothing to do with any business task or so.

Comment: There is a lock mechanism implemented in openMP. See the lock routined in this [reference card](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-4.0-C.pdf). There is also the `ordered` clause that can guarantee that some line in a for loop will be executed in an orderly fashion.